# How to add border to fabric js iText even when it is not active

Tags: fabricjs

I have the need to be able to display a rectangle with text inside but I need it to handle word wrap. I found in fabric.js github [issue #187](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/187) discussion about exactly what I needed for this. Also found in fabric.js [pull request 725](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/pull/725) where the commits were made relating to the issue. Additionally I found in the current master for the source code is the [textbox.class.js](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/master/src/shapes/textbox.class.js) that now exists for this,though its not yet in any Demos or Docs on the [fabricjs site](http://fabricjs.com/).

There are a few things I need to happen in the shape I'm trying to display

1. Must display text that when resized handles word wrap
2. Must display a background color
3. Must display a border color

Item 1 is addressed with the TextBox shape now available in the source code. I can address item 2 using the `backgroundColor` option when creating the object. What I need is the ability to apply a border. I can do this with a `fabric.Rect` using stroke but since `fabric.Textbox` extends `fabric.IText` applying a stroke affects the text and I don't need that. I did find I could get somewhat of what I need using a `fabric.Shadow` but it's still not distinct enough and I can't increase it very much since it applies the shadow to text as well.

I've put together a **plunk** [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hodT7RMFnwYxy9FzPgvK?p=preview) that shows an **example** what I currently have been trying. The need for the border is to give more separation in the boxes, as you'll notice in the example they are stacked cascading on top of each other and I will have possibly dozens of these on a screen at a time.

I thought to try and use a `fabric.Group` but I couldn't get it to work correctly having a `fabric.Rect` and a `fabric.Textbox` together, on resize the Textbox wouldn't handle the word wrap as it does when not in a Group.

Any suggestions on how I might be able to show a border? I would like to use `fabric.Textbox` and its options as much as possible to reduce number of shapes but the primary concern is adding a border. Thanks for your input.

Comment: no responses for this one?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this

```
canvas.getObjects()[0].drawBorders(canvas.getContext())
```

and may be implement your own `drawBorders` function and call it whenever the objects are not selected

Answer (score 1):

Extend Textbox and draw the border in the context by calling _renderTextBoxBackground after updating the border properties - borderWidth and borderColors

Answer (score 1):

I was also trying to do the same. Wanted to add Border to IText, tried searching for it all over internet then finally decided to override render method of IText like below.

```js
     var container = document.getElementById("container")
            var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
            var text =  fabric.util.createClass(fabric.IText, {
  
            
            render: function(ctx) {
              this.clearContextTop();
              this.callSuper('render', ctx);
              this.cursorOffsetCache = { };
              this.renderCursorOrSelection();
              /*var bound = this.getBoundingRect();
              ctx.strokeStyle = this.fill;  
              ctx.strokeRect(
            bound.left + 0.5,
            bound.top + 0.5,
            bound.width,
            bound.height
              );*/
              ctx.strokeStyle = this.fill;  
            let coords = this.calcCoords();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(coords.tl.x, coords.tl.y);
            ctx.lineTo(coords.tr.x, coords.tr.y);
            ctx.lineTo(coords.br.x, coords.br.y);
            ctx.lineTo(coords.bl.x, coords.bl.y);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();


              /*ctx.rect(this.left , this.top , this.width*this.scaleX , this.height*this.scaleY); 
              ctx.stroke();*/

            },
            /**
             * @private
             * @param {CanvasRenderingContext2D} ctx Context to render on
             */
            _render: function(ctx) {
              this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
            },
        });     
           let textt = new text('Baka',{
        bgColor: 'transparent',
        fill: 'red'
        });
canvas.add(textt);
canvas.renderAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.2.0/fabric.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

hachi09's answer didn't work for me with FabricJS 5.2.1. Here is a working example for 5.2.1

```js
fabric.BorderedIText =  fabric.util.createClass(fabric.IText, {
  type: 'BorderedIText',

  initialize: function(text, options) {
    options || (options = { });
    this.callSuper('initialize', text, options);
    this.set('showBorder', options.showBorder === undefined ? true : options.showBorder);
  },

  toObject: function() {
    return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
      showBorder: this.get('showBorder')
    });
  },

  render: function(ctx) {
    this.callSuper('render', ctx);

    if (this.showBorder) {
      const coords = this.getCoords();

      ctx.strokeStyle = this.fill;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.setLineDash([5, 10]);
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.moveTo(coords[0].x, coords[0].y);
      ctx.lineTo(coords[1].x, coords[1].y);
      ctx.lineTo(coords[2].x, coords[2].y);
      ctx.lineTo(coords[3].x, coords[3].y);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  },
});

fabric.BorderedIText.fromObject = function(object, callback) {
  return fabric.Object._fromObject('BorderedIText', object, callback, 'text');
};

var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
let textt = new fabric.BorderedIText('Dude!', {
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  bgColor: 'transparent',
  fill: 'red'
});
canvas.add(textt);
canvas.renderAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/521/fabric.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
</div>
```